# Subfields of $\mathbb Q(e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

> What are the subfields of $\mathbb Q(e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}})$ ?

Since $\displaystyle e^{\frac{i\pi}{4}}=\frac{\sqrt2+\sqrt{-2}}2$

So $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2), \mathbb Q(\sqrt{-2})$

and $\sqrt2\cdot\sqrt{-2}=\sqrt{-4}=2i$

Therefore $\mathbb Q(i)$ is another one

The problem is also, it is not written that the subfields must contain $\mathbb Q$

Are there finitely many then ?

Comment: **Any** field of characteristic zero contains (an isomorphic copy of) $\;\Bbb Q\;$ . And yes: there are only finitely many of them in this case.

Comment: @Timbuc and any subfield of a field inherits its characteristic ?

Comment: Of course, since the multiplicative unit in both **must** be the same, and thus $\;1+1+\ldots\;$ is the same in both.

Comment: Did I forget something ?

Comment: @Timbuc. It seems to me that the Galois groups is the Klein four group, or rather $\Bbb{Z}_8^*$. How did you get $D_4$?

Comment: Inequal, is it clear to you how you show that $\sqrt2\in\Bbb{Q}(e^{\pi i/4})$? It is, I'm not trying to trick you. It's just that it sounds like this your first course in field extensions and Galois theory, so at this stage you are supposed to include such details. At least I would, as a teacher, press the issue :-)

Comment: JyrkiLahtonen I didn't: I thought I was addressing the OP's claims but it is obvious I misplaced these comments in the wrong question *now that you addressed me* . Thanks, I shall delete the wrong comments.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen It is my first course, you've right. To your question:  to show that$\sqrt2\in\mathbb Q(e^{i\pi/4})$, can I write $\mathbb Q(e^{i\pi/4})=\mathbb Q(\sqrt2+\sqrt{-2})=\mathbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt{-2})$ deduce from there ? I saw something similar to second inequality, I cannot remember.

Comment: How do you write $\sqrt2$ using only $a=\sqrt2+\sqrt{-2}$, field operations, and rational numbers? In other words, there is no universal result stating that $\Bbb{Q}(a+b)=\Bbb{Q}(a,b)$. Each and every case needs a proof.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen $a^8/16?$ Yes it needs a proof, I assumed only that it is true here.

Comment: Let's see: $a=\sqrt2(1+i)$, so $a^2=2(1+i)^2=4i$, $a^4=-16$, $a^8=256$, so $a^8/16=16$. Try again! I would guess that you had an example in class showing why $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2+\sqrt3)=\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt3)$. Can you mimick that?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen apologize I scale it wrong, so dividing by 256 should be OK, but I mean how is the general approach to such a problem, yes that example, I've seen it not in the course but somewhere else

Comment: That's ok. Here's a hint. The number $a$ is complex, its argument (aka phase) is $\pi/4$. Therefore $1/a$ has phase $-\pi/4$. Can you find a linear combination (with rational coefficients) of them that gives a non-rational real number?

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen just for that $a$: since the addition of the arguments gives $0$, one has to check if the length are equal, here it is not. but $4(1/a)$ has the same length so $a+4(1/a)=2\sqrt2$, if I'm not wrong. But what did we do now ? justified that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt2+\sqrt{-2})=\mathbb Q(\sqrt2,\sqrt{-2})$

Comment: Well done! $a+4(1/a)=2\sqrt2$, so $2\sqrt2\in\Bbb{Q}(a)$. Therefore also $\sqrt2=(a/2)+(2/a)\in\Bbb{Q}(a)$. Therefore also $\sqrt{-2}=a-\sqrt2\in\Bbb{Q}(a)$. As both $\sqrt2$ and $\sqrt{-2}\in\Bbb{Q}(a)$ it follows that $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt{-2})\subseteq\Bbb{Q}(a)$. But trivially $\Bbb{Q}(a)\subseteq\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt2,\sqrt{-2})$, so they are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution which is elementary and avoids the use of Galois theory.

Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(e^{i\pi/4})$. Give an argument that $K = \mathbb{Q}(i,\sqrt{2})$. Show that $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=4$.

If $F$ is a subfield of $K$, then $F$ must contain $\mathbb{Q}$. Furthermore, $d=[F:\mathbb{Q}]$ must divide $[K:\mathbb{Q}] = 4$. Thus, $d=1,2,\text{ or }4$. If $d=4$ then $F=K$ and if $d=1$ then $F=\mathbb{Q}$.

It remains to understand the case when $d=2$. In this case, since $F$ is a quadratic field over $\mathbb{Q}$ we can say that $F = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{n})$ where $n$ is a square-free integer. Now use this to find the possible values of $n$.

Comment: @I Love Mr. Paul $-1,2,-2$ ?

Comment: Yes! Those are the possible values for $n$. (Of course, you need to give an argument to why, but if you see this, then you found all the fields).